# Count if excel not working for letter C

Tags: excel

My `count if` function won't work for the letter "C". I checked for spaces with `len` function and I am super confused. Thanks for the help.

```
    #of Accident Type   
A   28
B   19
C   =COUNTIF(A2:A101, "*C*")
D   17
E   9
F   9

Accidents
A
B
D
A
A
F
C
A
C
B
E
B
A
C
F
D
B
C
D
A
A
C
B
E
B
C
E
A
B
A
A
A
B
C
C
D
F
D
B
B
A
F
C
B
A
C
B
E
E
D
A
B
C
E
A
A
F
C
B
D
D
D
B
D
C
A
F
A
A
B
D
E
A
E
D
B
C
A
F
A
C
D
D
A
A
B
A
F
D
C
A
C
B
F
D
A
E
A
C
D
```

Comment: @pnuts I did that to match the manner in which the poster had actually posted the data.  Since he had posted it in a single column, it seemed to me that is how he would have wanted it to appear.  It is not unusual for people to have trouble with markdown formatting when they first arrive here.

Comment: @pnuts Opinions obviously vary.  I prefer the column format. It clarified that the information was in a single column. It made a copy/paste operation simpler. It helped me to better understand the question and decide whether or not to respond. And the time spent to have it appear that way was, what, maybe three seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine, but I did not put the asterisks. Each cell (copied form the data example you gave) only has the character : no spaces...

[image]

Comment: @pnuts I don’t believe the small change in the position of the data detracts from the demonstration of the technique...

Comment: In fact, I would normally name the data range. - did not do that as it may have been more confusing. My data ended up starting in A5 after copying the text left in the op’s question and transposing it...

Comment: But I think this is a waste of time as the OP won’t be accepting or even voting for any of the answers provided...

Answer (score 0):

Probably it does not work, because the `C` is written in Cyrillic. To make sure, whether this is the case, write `C` in English additionally and try to change the font to something Fancy - e.g. `Algerian`. Then the two `C` will be obviously different:

[image]

Comment: @pnuts - it's just a theory. :) You never know, cyrillic is a famous alphabet, it can be that he is having a client somewhere or anything else :)

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A101,"*C*" )
```

For some reason its working now... I changed the font and messed around with it. 
Thanks again for the help!!!!